# When did cross-checking become illegal in the NHL?

Tags: rules, history, ice-hockey, nhl

Does anybody know when the NHL prohibited cross-checking?

Cross-checking occurs when a player checks an opponent by using the shaft of his or her stick with both hands [See Rule 59.1 of the NHL Rulebook 2015-6]. I saw that players were suspended in the 80s for that, but it might be an even older rule.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell it has always been a rule. [This article](http://www.rauzulusstreet.com/hockey/nhlhistory/nhlrules.html) references all major rule changes in the NHL since 1910, and cross-checking is not listed whatsoever. So I think it was probably a rule at the NHL's conception.